# I'm trying to test a laravel live site into my local computer but image not showing. can somebody help me?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have setup the backup files locally and import database into a local database, all post text showing from database but images are not showing.

I'v run the php artisan storage:link command, However images are not showing.

Comment: Difficult to help without more details :-) Could it be a permissions issue ? What happens when you directly access an image url into your browser ? Please provide : application base url, an image full url and its"value" into database.

Comment: Need more details to help

Answer (score 0):

Maybe u need to give full access on your laravel storage path.

```
chmod 777 storage
```